# How to split report page into four parts (crystal report + C#)

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

**Hi, how can I split the page into four parts? like the image**

[image]

Comment: is it for labeling purpose? Hope you aware of "Format with Multiple columns" option

Comment: Sub report can do this: